# User Name in Header in Jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have an application with spring + spring security. In my application I have a header, in that header I have the user name, but this user name is only present in my first page, If i change the page, the user name disappears.
I know tha I can get the user name with Principal, but I would like avoid write Principal in every controller. Are there other way to keep the name in the header?

Answer (score 1):

You ca use Spring Security jsp tags http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

Comment: thank you, i'll try with <sec:authentication property="principal.username" />

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download jar file of spring-security-taglib or add maven dependency if you are using maven. 
Download jar from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs/3.2.0.RELEASE

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then Add URI in header

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

and then you can use spring security tags, for example-

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your jsp files wher eyou want username displayed :

```
<%@include file="header.jsp" %>
```

Where header is the jsp that contains the reference to principal.username. Will work as long as you have a princial in secruity context.

Or even better define your own custom jstl tag...